# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Hola buen dia estoy trabajando con react. Cuando intento manejar hooks me sale el siguiente error:

×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Sin embargo he revisado y no logro dar con la razon

Mi package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "roadbook-v1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/material": "latest",
    "@mui/icons-material": "latest",
    "@emotion/styled": "latest",
    "@emotion/react": "latest",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^3.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "recharts": "^2.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/reset" component={Reset} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

y finalmente la url que trato de acceder:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithGoogle } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import "../login.css";

//UI
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));

export default function Login() {
    //const classes = useStyles();

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    const history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (loading) {
            // maybe trigger a loading screen
            return;
        }
        if (user) history.replace("/dashboard");
    }, [user, loading]);
    return (
        <div className="login">
            <Grid
                container
                direction="column"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center"
                spacing={2}
            >
                <Grid item>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="login__textBox"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="E-mail Address"
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        className="login__textBox"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Password"
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained" color="primary"
                        onClick={() => signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)}
                    >
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained" color="secondary"
                        onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
                        Login with Google
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <div>
                    <Link to="/reset">Forgot Password</Link>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Don't have an account? <Link to="/register">Register</Link> now.
                </div>
            </Grid>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Y si creas un function handler para  `signInWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithGoogle ` en vez de llamarlas inline.